# Going to next line with fgetl in loop

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to read a RINEX file (it's a GNSS file with observations). I'm using fgetl and I know how to do that when everything is in one line. But when there is more that 13 observations some of them skip to next line and here's my problem. How can I staying in loop read next line? Here is a code that I use:

```
while x==0
m=8
m=10
    Line1=fgetl(fid);
    if findstr(Line1,'SYS / # / OBS TYPES')
        if Line1(1)=='G'
            Obs_num=str2num(Line1(5:6))
            if Obs_num>13
                for i=1:13
                    G=Line1(m:n)
                    G_obs_type{i}=[G]
                    m=m+4;
                    n=n+4;

                end
%Here I want to skip to next line, read what is there and add to "G_obs_type, eventual do it somewhere where it will work"
            elseif Obs_num<=13
                for i=1:Obs_num
                    G=Line1(m:n)
                    G_obs_type{i}=[G]
                    m=m+4;
                    n=n+4;
                end
                x=1;
                frewind(fid)
            end

     end
end
```

File look like that:

```
G   16 C1C C2W C2X C5X D1C D2W D2X D5X L1C L2W L2X L5X S1C  SYS / # / OBS TYPES
       S2W S2X S5X                                          SYS / # / OBS TYPES
```

Comment: Why not use `fgetl` again, after the loop (`for i=1:13`)?

Comment: Wow, this solution was so easy that I even didn't think about it. Thanks a lot for help!